# Cross-browser textarea properties (attributes?) spellcheck, lang, and wrap

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, textarea

My application needs a `textarea` where the user can configure some of the behaviour:

1. toggle wrapping long lines
2. toggle the browser's spellchecker
3. choose the language for the textarea (the application will be multi-lingual and the user will be changing languages while using it)

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SynFs/1/

(Feel free to comment on the style / efficiency of my HTML, JS, and CSS; I'm always looking to improve)

I'm trying to take advantage of `HTML5` features.

Toggling wrapping and spellchecking by manipulating the `textarea`'s properties / attributes in `jQuery` (`.prop('wrap', 'off')` and `.attr('spellcheck','false')` work perfectly in Firefox 27.0 but don't appear to work for Opera 19 and IE 10 (I have no other browsers / platforms available for me to check other permutations).

**Wrapping**

I have searched for solutions and have seen suggestions related to manipulating `css` `white-space` between `normal` and `nowrap` but that seems to lose the line breaks and switching it off then back on doesn't give you back what you started with.

Although `.prop('wrap','off')` works in FF 27, it doesn't seem to have any effect in Opera 18 and IE 10.

I have read discussions about `wrap` being non-standard and I'll be happy for a css-only solution if there is one.  Any suggestions?

**Spellcheck**

Similar to wrapping, FF 27 responds as expected with `.attr('spellcheck', 'true')` (**NB** string not boolean) but not quite with Opera 19 and IE 10.  IE 10 leaves the red squiggly underlining and once spellcheck has been set to false, it doesn't bother rechecking after it's changed back to 'true.'  Opera 19 doesn't seem to take any notice.

Is it possible to selectively enable / disable spell checking?  It seems plausible according to MDN developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms

**Language choice**

I have 2 problems here (so far…).  First, I'm not sure if it's `.prop` or `.attr` because I can't seem to make either work.  Which is it and how do I make it work?

Second, I haven't been able to find an exhaustive yet sensible list of language-region pairs.  I've seen many many documents discussing / defining the format and endless acronyms (BCP47, IETF, i18n, ISO 639, ISO 15924, ISO 3166-1, LCID, and UN M.49…).  I can find tools which can check if a combination is currently registered.  I can find lists of ISO-639-2 (and -3) language codes and of ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes.  Yet I can't find a list of language-country pairs.  I did find this msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx list of old Microsoft codes but I wasn't sure if it's appropriate.  If I've learnt one thing today it's that there are many standards related to language- and country-codes…

Does any one know of an existing list?  It doesn't have to be perfect and I'm happy to extract the contents from a table and manipulate it into the correct lang-country format.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-layout-center">Everything in this fiddle will be contained within a pane (jQuery UI Layout plugin, layout.jquery-dev.net) which overrides some of the CSS</div>
<div id="pane-west" class="ui-layout-west no-scrollbar" style="height:100%">
    <div id="jqui-tab">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1">Some content
            <div class="vexpand borderbox">
                <form> <span title="(de)activate line wrapping"><input name="ta-controls" id="cb-wrap" type="checkbox" value="wrap" checked="checked" /><label for="cb-wrap">wrap long lines</label></span>
 <span class="spacer" title="(de)activate spell checking"><input name="ta-controls" id="cb-spell" type="checkbox" value="check" checked="checked" /><label for="cb-spell">check spelling</label></span>
 <span class="spacer" title="set the language / region"><select name="ta-controls" id="sl-lang">

     <optgroup label="English"><option value="en">English</option> 
  <option value="en-us" selected>English (United States)</option>
                <option value="en-gb">English (United Kingdom)</option></optgroup>
     <optgroup label="French"><option value="fr">French</option><option value="fr-ca">French (Canada)</option></optgroup>
     </select></span>

                </form>
                <textarea id="txtarea" class="borderbox" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">Analyse this then analyze that. C'est magnifique n'est pas? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris rhoncus viverra velit vitae sollicitudin. Ut at eleifend mi. Pellentesque non posuere ipsum. Nullam fermentum purus mauris, sed vestibulum enim venenatis eu. Integer sit amet vestibulum nisl, iaculis hendrerit metus. Nullam lacinia pretium aliquam. Donec non euismod libero. Nam ac leo in est vestibulum dignissim malesuada id elit. Praesent tempus malesuada luctus. Nunc posuere elementum lectus, quis malesuada eros varius ac. Proin consequat risus tincidunt massa convallis fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed eget pellentesque ante.</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">This tab's content are unrelated</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.ui-layout-center {
    background:#eee
}
.ui-tabs-panel {
    padding:0!important
}
.no-scrollbar {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.spacer {
    margin-left:1.5em;
}
.borderbox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    /* the full jQuery UI Layout css will override some of these */
    resize: vertical;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    height: calc(100% - 22px);
    margin:0
}
.vexpand {
    /* the full jQuery UI Layout css will override some of these */
    margin-left:0.2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 95%;
    width: calc(100% - 1em);
    height: 98%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

JS:

```
var ta = $('#txtarea'),
    layout = $('body').layout({
        west__resizable: false,
        west__size: 0.95
    });
$('#cb-spell').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ta.attr('spellcheck', 'true')
    } else {
        ta.attr('spellcheck', 'false')
    }
    //ta.val(ta.val()) // attempt at adding / removing the red under-squiggles in IE 10 and Opera 19
}).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');

$('#cb-wrap').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ta.css('white-space', 'normal')
        ta.prop('wrap', 'on')
    } else {
        ta.css('white-space', 'nowrap')
        ta.prop('wrap', 'off')
    }
});

$('#sl-lang').on('change', function (e) {
    //ta.attr('lang', $(this).val()) // is lang an attribute?
    ta.prop('lang', $(this).val()) // or a property?
    .focus() // refreshes the textarea, hopefully
}).trigger('change'); // set the default

$('#jqui-tab').tabs({
    heightStyle: 'fill',
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade'
});
```

Comment: Please show us some code and what you have tried. If you can, set up an example  jsfiddle.net

Comment: There's a link to the fiddle just after the initial list of requirements :)